# Versioning of xml files and serialization to C# objects

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a collection of POCOs that I am serializing to xml using the xmlserializer and streamwriter/streamreader.

My xml file will be on the web for my app to get updates from. I am concerned that if version 2 of my app comes out and needs to change the schema, it breaking the installed version 1 base.

I have read about versioning and find it a little confusing on determining the fool-proof method.

Can someone tell me what the best options are to handle this?

Am I just better off giving my new xml file a new filename with each new version?

Does an xslt address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways of doing this. Depending on how your app determines if the file is newer you can add a tag to the xml specifying the schema version or you can add a code to the filename. The one problem with XSLT I see is you will need to make a new one for each new version and doesn't really work if you want to add tags to your schema. Hope this gives you something to work with.